# How do we apply the theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

The statement of Division Algorithm is,
Given integers a and d, d =/= 0, there exist unique integers, q and
r, such that a = qd + r,with 0 <= r < |d|
We can state it in this way,
If a and d are integers such that  d =/= 0 THEN, there exist unique
integers, q and r, such that a = qd + r,with 0 <= r < |d|
Now,suppose we have integers 'a' of this form,
a=2q+1
where a and q are integers.
Now,I have seen written in my textbook that if we have integers of
this form then it is not divisible by '2' as it leaves remainder '1'.
What I DO NOT understand is that how do we KNOW that 1 is remainder?
I think it uses DIVISION LEMMA.
By looking at "a=2q+1" we can only determine two things.
First,that we have two integers q and 1 such that 0<=1<2.(similar to

the conclusion of the division algorithm) 
second,2q+1=a
BUT how can this INFORMATION (.....two integers q and 1(r) such that
0<=1<2 AND 2q+1=a) MAKE us say that '1' is remainder?
HOW DO WE APPLY THE DIVISION ALGORITHM TO CLAIM THAT '1' IS REMAINDER?
(****I KNOW THAT WE CAN APPLY A THEOREM ONLY IF THE "REQUIRED
CONDITION" or THE CONDITION WHICH IS MENTIONED AFTER 'IF.......' IS
TRUE****) 
Please Mention the steps you follow for applying the theorem.

Comment: So.. if we have a cat named Irving how do we know it's name is Irving?  We are have 1) a=2q+1 and 2) 0 < 1 <2 and 3) given a there is a *unique* expression a=2q+r 0 <= r <2.  So a=2q+1 is such an expression.  And it is the unique expression.  So r= 1.  And we call r the "remainder" what the heck is there to not know?

Comment: Indeed, the unique $r$ in the division algorithm is called the remainder, it's a _definition_ of the term "remainder". But people thinking it's a good idea to shout at people just because they didn't understand simple things may need more than any answer we could come up with, here.

Answer (score 0):

"Unique" means there is only one possible way of doing it.

a=2n+1 is one way of doing it.

So a=2n+1 is the only way of doing it.

So if a=2q+r is the *unique* way of doing it.  And a=2n+1 is the *only* way of doing it.  Then q=n and r=1.

There is simply no other possible interpretation.